# how to use object of a class into another class in php

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php 

class connect {
public $_link,$_result,$_num_rows;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","news");
}

public function query($sql) {

    $_result = $this->_link->query($sql);
    return $this->_result;
}
public function num_rows($result) {
    $this->_num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    return $this->_num_rows;
}
}
```

---

```
<?php 
require "../model/connect.php";
$db = new connect();
$mydoLogin = new doLogin($db);

class doLogin  {
protected $mycon ;
public function __construct($mycon) {
    $this->mycon = $mycon;
}
public function is_user_exist($user,$pass) {
    $sql = "select * from user where username=$user and password=$pass";
    $result = $this->mycon->_link->query($sql);
    return ($this->mycon->num_rows($result) == 1);
    //var_dump($result);
 }



}
```

I have to classes, first a connect class and then a doLogin class, so I want to use an instance of the connect class into doLogin class but when I want to use it i face much of errors, sometimes it says the mycon variable is not defined or sth... the point is here that I tryed many times to create the instance directly into doLogin class but I couldn't. help me for comming this problem over. thanks!

Comment: Paste code a text please.

Comment: i am editing...wait plz

Comment: Where did you get `_link` from in `$this->mycon->_link->.....`

Comment: And what does Javascript have to do with this? Don't tag something just because it might be listed in the related box, only tag something if it has something to do with your problem

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: No, dont try and add the images to the question. Paste code as text indented by 4 chars to make it show in a code block

Comment: the code is posted right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Here i have two classes,
1)Main.php ->create one contrsuct() function do the connection inside the function for example </p>
<pre>

class Main {
    protected $conn = null;
public function __construct(){

try{
    $this->conn = new PDO(DB_TYPE.":host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e){

echo '<h3>Database Not Connected</h3>','<p>Please Check database connection before running this site ...</p>'; 
exit;

}

}
}

</pre>
<p>inside the same class only create another function for login for example</p>
<pre>
 public function isLogged($sessionId, $url){
    if(isset($_SESSION[$sessionId])){
        $this->redirect($url);
    }
}
</pre>

now create another class it extends main class and doing the login calculation
for example:-

    <pre>


  Class Login extends Main{
       public function loginCollege($username,$password)
    {
        try{
            $stmnt=$this->conn->prepare("select id from colleges where(email=:user or phone=:user)  AND phone=:pswd");
            $stmnt->bindParam("user", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
            $stmnt->bindParam("pswd", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
            $stmnt->execute();
            $count=$stmnt->rowCount();
            $res=$stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $id = $res['id'];
            if($count){
                $_SESSION['id']= $id;
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }

    }
   }

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do it for connecting to the database, try to use one class of connection, and use another file and don't create a class and create instance of that class into you second file.